# Unable to mock a service to have it throw an exception

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-boot, junit, mockito

I'm new to using Mockito for unit-testing Spring Rest controllers. Here is my controller and my test code.

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/food/customer")
public class CustomerController {
    @Autowired
    private CustomerService service;

    @RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.POST, produces= MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public ResponseEntity<Customer> addCustomer(@RequestBody Customer c){
        Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(CustomerController.class.getName());
        try {
            service.addCustomer(c);
        } catch (UserNameException e){
            log.error("UserNameException", e);
            return new ResponseEntity(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
        } catch (Exception e){
            log.error("", e);
            return new ResponseEntity(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
        }
        log.trace("Customer added: " + c.toString());
        return new ResponseEntity(c, HttpStatus.CREATED);
    }
}

@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
@WebMvcTest
public class CustomerRestTest {
    private MockMvc mockMvc;
    @Mock
    private CustomerService customerService;
    @Mock
    private CustomerDao customerDao;
    @InjectMocks
    private CustomerController customerController;

    @Before
    public void setup(){
        this.mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup(customerController).build();
    }

    @Test
    public void testAddDuplicateCustomer() throws Exception {
        Customer myCustomer = mock(Customer.class);
        when(customerService.addCustomer(myCustomer)).thenThrow(UserNameException.class);
        String content = "{\"lastName\" : \"Orr\",\"firstName\" : \"Richard\",\"userName\" : \"Ricky\"}";
        RequestBuilder requestBuilder = MockMvcRequestBuilders.post("/api/food/customer").accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).
                content(content).contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
        MvcResult result = mockMvc.perform(requestBuilder).andReturn();
        MockHttpServletResponse response = result.getResponse();
        assertEquals(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST.value(), response.getStatus());
    }
}
```

I'm attempting to mock my service layer and have it throw my custom exception when *addCustomer* is called. I'm getting back HttpStatus.CREATED instead of BAD_REQUEST. What can I do differently with the service mock line (the one with thenThrow) that may work properly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I assume this is because you expect a **specific customer instance inside your `when` clause** but this never happens. Spring will deserialize your JSON and will set another customer instance to your method.

Try changing this:

```
when(customerService.addCustomer(myCustomer)).thenThrow(UserNameException.class);
```

to this:

```
when(customerService.addCustomer(any())).thenThrow(UserNameException.class);
```

Comment: That did it! Thanks dzatorsky.

Comment: Wow. Wow. Wow. Have been stuck for 5 hours just to find out finally with this answer that I have to replace Mockito.anyString with Mockito.any.